# Splitting a BeautifulSoup into 2 Soup-Trees

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

There are various ways to split a beautifulSoup parsetree getting a list of the elements or getting the strings of the tags.
But there seems to be no way to keep the tree intact while splitting it.

I want to split the following snippet (soup) on the `<br />`'s. Trivial with strings, but I want to keep the structure, I want a list of parsetrees.

```
s="""<p>
foo<br />
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar<br />
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar<br />
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar<br />
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
</p>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(s)
```

I could, obviously, do a `[BeautifulSoup(i) for i in str(soup).split('<br />')]`, but I that's ugly and I have way too many links for that.

Iterating with soup.next and soup.previousSibling() on soup.findAll('br') is possible, but returns not a parsetree, but only all elements it contains.

Is there a solution extracting a full subtree of tags from a BeautifulSoup-tag, keeping all parent- and sibling-relations?

edit for more clarity:

The result should be a list consisting of BeautifulSoup-Objects, that I can traverse the splitted soup further down, by output[0].a, output[1].text and so on.
Splitting a soup on the `<br />`s would return a list of all links to process further, which is what I need. All links from the snippet above, with text, attributes and the following "bar", being a description of each link.

Comment: Sorry, what output do you expect exactly? A tree without `<br/>` tags in it? Should the `<p>` tag still have a parent (if there was one before)? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't have to remove the `<br/>` tags at all to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind that the original tree is changed, I'd use `.extract()` on the `<br />` tags to simply remove them from the tree:

```
>>> for br in soup.find_all('br'): br.extract()
... 
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
>>> soup
<html><body><p>
foo
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
</p></body></html>
```

This is a full working tree still:

```
>>> soup.p
<p>
foo
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a> | bar
</p>
>>> soup.p.a
<a href="http://...html" target="_blank">foo</a>
```

But you do not need to remove those tags at all to achieve what you want:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link['href'], ''.join(link.stripped_strings), link.next_sibling
```

results in:

```
>>> for link in soup.find_all('a'):
...     print link['href'], ''.join(link.stripped_strings), link.next_sibling
... 
http://...html foo  | bar
http://...html foo  | bar
http://...html foo  | bar
http://...html foo  | bar
```

regardless of wether or not we removed the `<br/>` tags from the tree first.

Comment: I edited by post above to clarify my target. A list of all links.

Comment: The problem with the answer is that it doesn't answer my general question for a result of a whole tag, it instead returns still only strings. It's just a more complicated version of `str(soup).split('<br />')`. But, as always, it is enough for my specific "link list with all information" I need for my project, so thanks... ;)

Comment: @sistason: I gave you an output example; it does *not* return strings, I only print the extracted info. You can return these `a` tags and extract that same information elsewhere.

Comment: whoops, link['href'] is a string, link obviously not. Sorry for the wrong interpretation. It returns a tree, I was blind. It baffles me that, in the end, find_all() was the solution from the start. Thanks